# Is the white spot disease from gold fish contagious for turtles?

Tags: fish, turtles

Sadly, a few sets of gold fish have died continuously due to a sudden infection of the white spot disease that has contaminated the tank. I was looking to place my turtles in that tank as they are getting a little too big for their own. Just wanted to know if the white spot disease would spread on them? Thanks

Comment: I think you mean [ick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ichthyophthirius_multifiliis) for the "white sport disease"

Comment: if it's effectively ick I don't think the turtle can catch it according to the last post [here](http://www.tortoiseforum.org/threads/can-aquatic-turtles-be-affected-by-ich.7863/). Forum aren't really autoritative source but still better than nothing

Answer (score 3):

Ich, also known as "white spot disease," is a disease that affects freshwater fish such as goldfish (there is a marine variant as well). Being a reptile, turtles are not at risk for ich and so won't be infected.

However, having said that, I would strongly advise against just putting them in that tank with out a proper cleaning. The water is probably not generally healthy, as a result of any ich treatments you may have made and the dead fish that have passed through it. You'll want to ensure a healthy environment is not only a start point, but a maintained one, for your turtles.

As an aside, don't put any fish in with the turtles, they'll only become food.